# Android - Add imageView to background

Tags: android, android-layout

Im trying to add an image to the activity background so that if there is no internet connection it will show a full screen image as well. I have the image but I can't get it to show up. This is my code.

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        android.net.NetworkInfo wifi = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
        android.net.NetworkInfo datac = cm
                .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
        if ((wifi != null & datac != null)
                && (wifi.isConnected() | datac.isConnected())) {
                CookieManager cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance(); 
                cookieManager.setAcceptCookie(true); 

                webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
                webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
                       public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                        MainActivity.this.setProgress(progress * 1000);
                       }
                     });
                     webView.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {
                       public void onReceivedError(WebView view, int errorCode, String description, String failingUrl) {
                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "An error occurred " + description, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       }
                     });

                     webView.loadUrl("http://mysite.com/?ma=1");
               }
                 else{
 this ----->      ImageView iv = new ImageView(this); 
                  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noconnect);
                  iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                  Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "No Internet Connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
                  toast.show();  

        }

    }

    private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (Uri.parse(url).getHost().equals("mysite.com")) {
                return false;
            }
            // Otherwise, the link is not for a page on my site, so launch another Activity that handles URLs
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webView.canGoBack()) {
            webView.goBack();
            return true;
        } 
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) 
    {
        switch (item.getItemId()) 
        {
            case R.id.logout:
                finish();
                return true;
        }
      return false;
    }


}
```

EDIT: here is the XML, this way it causing it to crash when loading.

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
              android:orientation="vertical" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:id="@+id/pmlayout" >

     <ImageView 
       android:id="@+id/noconn"
       android:background="@drawable/noconnect"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="fill_parent"
       android:scaleType="matrix"
       android:visibility="visible" >
     </ImageView>

     <WebView android:id="@+id/webview" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**Edit 2:**

This is the crash errors im now getting.

```
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.site.testapp/com.site.testapp.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.webkit.WebView
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2088)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2113)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:139)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1224)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4918)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1004)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:771)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.ImageView cannot be cast to android.webkit.WebView
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at me.publicize.testapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:30)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5048)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2052)
04-07 18:51:17.920: E/AndroidRuntime(8113):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add this image to you layout, you first need to assign an id you your Activity layout.
then find it using the:

```
findViewByid(id);
```

for example:

```
LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewByid (R.id.llayout);
```

and then add the ImageView to the layout:

```
linearLayout.addView(iv);
```

Comment: Thanks again for helping. I tried this but still not working. ImageView iv = new ImageView(this); 
                  iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.noconnect);
                  LinearLayout playout = (LinearLayout) findViewById (R.id.pmlayout);
                  playout.addView(iv);
                  iv.setAdjustViewBounds(true);

Comment: as I told you in the privious post try to put the image view in the xml file and set it visibility to false, then in code just change it's visibility to not deal with this problem. it should work... do you get any error massage?

Comment: Ok I added android:visibility="invisible" to the XML imaageView. In the activity I use this  
                  ImageView iv=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.noconn);
                  iv.setVisibility(ImageView.VISIBLE);  That is not working either. Why are things so complicated. :/

Comment: Try  iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); instead, do you see the image in the graphical designer?

Comment: I posted the XML file. The way the file is now, causes the app to crash when it loads. If I put webview before imageView it does not crash so something is wrong.

Comment: well your layout looks fine, it has nothing to do with it. what error do you receive when it crashes?

Comment: I ended up removing the ImageView as I think it conflicted with the webView. Anyway, I'll accept your answer because it probably would work if not for a webView. I figured out that I had to set the background to the webView not the layout and then it would only change the color. Because webView serves webpages it wouldn't take an image. I had to create a local html file with the image in it, load that file with webView and then it would display as needed. What a headache but it works as I wanted it to. Thanks